# implementing a vocabulary app for android and pc with a shared database

Tags: android, dictionary, cross-platform, vocabulary

I am starting to develop a vocabulary app out of necessity without good prior knowledge of the tools that I will have to use. Please excuse the nooby question:  your answers, even short and vague, will save me lots of time...

The app is supposed to store entries made by user (words) and display them for learning purposes. Once the words are entered from a mobile device, the database should be accordingly updated on PC. If the entries are made from PC, the database is updated on the mobile phone. What is an adequate way to implement this? If written in C# with SQLite, the database file would have to be imported/exported each time the entries are made which would be painful.

I have just a guess that a kind of a web app will suite the purpose. From you I only need general directions: what languages, what techonology/software/tools. Thank you and sorry for the type of question!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately your question is too broad for SO and is more suited to a forum or reddit or similar. SO is designed for specific programming questions in a Q&A format. I'm flagging to close this question. I recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated, you're only at the beginning.
But in order to give you a general guideline to help you started, I would save the DB in firebase DB solutions (they used to have one, now there two). Then, you'll have read and write access to it both from your PC client and your Android client (and any other client that is connected to the internet, like iPhone as well for that matter).
This also lets you to pick any programming language you'd like.

Firebase is Google's set of many handy tools and libraries that help during software and app development. You can read more at the official site: https://firebase.google.com/.